# Windows - Connect Docker Container API to Postgres database on localhost machine outside container

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, docker, containers

I have .net6 web api containerized trying to access postgresql hosted on local machine(windows) but it throws error:

Failed to connect to [::1]:5433
---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5433

c# api connection string in appSettings.json below;

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "conn1": "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5433; user id=postgres;Password=xxx;Database=xxx;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
  }
```

Comment: Please provide more info. When does the error occur? When you run the docker container? Show the command how you run the container, also the dockerfile code might be useful.